# COMO INSERTAR VIDEO EN REMOTO

Tags: html, web, video, youtube

Teniendo el código:

```
    <section class="video-container">
    <video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay loop muted disablepictureinpicture>
        <source src="./assets/videos/Main.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Tu navegador no soporta el elemento de video.
    </video>
</section>
```

Como puedo conseguir que el video no este en mis ficheros, sino en otro sitio web, poniendo en source el enlace del mismo y que se reproduzca manteniendo las flags `autoplay loop muted disablepictureinpicture`

Esto lo necesito porque algunos videos son muy pesados, lo cual relantiza la carga de mi web hasta que el navegador termine de bajarse el video por primera vez.

Gracias.

Comment: La respuesta es tal cual como lo haces desde tu servidor, pero colocando la otra ruta siempre y cuando el otro servidor permita intercambio de orígenes cruzados (CORS). Esto no va a solucionar tu problema, el archivo seguirá pesando lo mismo, lo que debes hacer es hacer un streaming del video. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource