# PORQUE NO CARGA VIDEO DE MI WEB EN NAVEGADORES IPHONE

Tags: html, video, chrome, iphone, safari

Teniendo el siguiente codigo de ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>Página en Construcción | Nacional Music Club</title>
....
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="left-section">

            <video autoplay muted loop>
                <source src="./assets/videos/Anuncio.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Tu navegador no soporta el tag de video.
            </video>

            <a href="https://www.nacionalmusicclub.es/" class="logo"><img src="./assets/images/N_simple.png" width="17%"
                    alt="Nacional Music Club"></a>

        </div>

        <div class="right-section">

            <div class="error-container">
                <img src="./assets/images/logoDoradoCustom.png" width="17%" alt="Nacional Music Club">
                <h4 class="error-title">¡Ups! En construcción</h4>
                <p class="error-message">Estamos trabajando en esta sección. Pronto estará disponible.</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Y entrando tanto por **Safari** como por **Google Chrome** desde un iPhone, el video no carga y se queda en el primer frame de el. En cambio en cualquier navegador desde la vista de un ordenador, incluso en un iPad no hay problema.
Lo he comprobado con los dispositivos iPhone de otras personas y persiste el problema. Lo pueden comprobar vostros mismo:

https://www.nacionalmusicclub.es/

También, puede ser problema del post que he realizado hace un momento: [COMO INSERTAR VIDEO EN REMOTO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/611475/349097)

Gracias.

Comment: No entiendo estas insertando un video que explica como insertar un video, pero tu no lo haces caso a ese video :S .-  Una etiqueta video debe tener un video, en cambio la URL `https://www.youtube.com/embed/iReoQzBaRhs?si=uUKfftBafE17a8Gi` te devuelve una página

Comment: puede ser debido al "codec" utilizado para el video, iphone si bien soporta el contenedor "mp4" puede no soportar la forma en que fue codificado el video; 
los tags `source` pueden ser varios, asi que podes poner un source con una version `webm` ( que iphone no soporta en todos los modelos ) y luego un source con una version especifica para iphone ( mp4 -> H.265 o H.264 ) . vale decir q si la version para iphone anda en otros navegadores y la calidad y peso son aceptables podes dejar un solo source

Comment: Entonces, exporto mi video .mp4 a uno compatible con iPhone (H.265 o H.264) y agrego abajo del source ya creado `<source src="./assets/videos/Anuncio.h265" type="video/h265">` deberia de funcionar?